# Broadcasting live video on Facebook

Tags: facebook, streaming, broadcast

Is it possible to share a live stream in HLS format on Facebook? If yes, is there support in the Facebook API? The only references I could find were old (back in 2010 / 2011). There were a few providers claiming they would live broadcast, but in fact it was a video upload.

Comment: No, there currently is no such service via the API and as far as I know not even on Facebook itself.